# View Unity Dependency Configuration in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

We have a lot of registrations within out Unity Container.  About 800 lines long in fact.

As Unity does not have a validate method, we introduced a Unit Test to verify the configuration before we test the application which looks like something as follows which works very well and has picked up lots of issues within the configuration:

```
IUnityContainer container = UnityContainerBuilder.Build();
foreach (ContainerRegistration mapping in container.Registrations)
{
    container.Resolve(mapping.RegisteredType, mapping.Name);
}
```

However, we have lots of classes that follow the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) in there where we use named registrations.  These named registrations are then used to build up the InjectionConstructor for other registrations, for example:

```
container.RegisterType<IMyType2, Concrete1MyType2>("Concrete1MyType2", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IMyType2, Concrete2MyType2>("Concrete2MyType2", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IMyType1, Concrete1MyType1>(
    "Concrete1MyType1", 
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<IMyType2>("Concrete2MyType2")));
```

Is it possible to access through some code what you have configured in the InjectionConstructor's for your registrations?

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660863(v=pandp.20).aspx) seems to suggest you can.

The example given is:

```
void DisplayContainerRegistrations(IUnityContainer theContainer)
{
    string regName, regType, mapTo, lifetime;
    Console.WriteLine("Container has {0} Registrations:",
            theContainer.Registrations.Count());
    foreach (ContainerRegistration item in theContainer.Registrations)
    {
    regType = item.RegisteredType.Name;
    mapTo = item.MappedToType.Name;
    regName = item.Name ?? "[default]";
    lifetime = item.LifetimeManagerType.Name;
    if (mapTo != regType)
    {
        mapTo = " -> " + mapTo;
    }
    else
    {
        mapTo = string.Empty;
    }
    lifetime = lifetime.Substring(0, lifetime.Length - "LifetimeManager".Length);
    Console.WriteLine("+ {0}{1}  '{2}'  {3}", regType, mapTo, regName, lifetime);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nikolia - I came across that one before.  It basically shows you what type mappings you have and the lifetime manager.  I want to know what I have configured with the InjectionConstructors.  The article doesn't cover that.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after not getting much info on this, I had a look at the internals of Unity as I could not see any public way of doing it.  I came up with the following which uses Reflection to access the private members of the various parts of Unity.

The main reasoning for this is that injecting Transient instances into Singletons is a bit of a mismatch.  Transient should only last a short time whilst Singletons will probably remain throughout the life of the DI Container.  There is some nice information on Simple Injector [here](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/LifestyleMismatches.html).  This was one of the reasons for trying to get the Injection information as Unity does not have a verify like Simple Injector.

So, here are my service interfaces and classes I am registering.  There are 3 interfaces and 3 concrete implementations with exception to IService2 which has 2 implementations.

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    private readonly IService2 _service2;
    private readonly IService3 _service3;

    public Service1(IService2 service2, IService3 service3)
    {
        _service2 = service2;
        _service3 = service3;
    }

    public int DoSomethingForService1()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

public interface IService1
{
    int DoSomethingForService1();
}

public class Service2 : IService2
{
    public int DoSomethingForService2()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

public class Service3 : IService3
{
    public int DoSomethingForService3()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

public interface IService3
{
    int DoSomethingForService3();
}

public class Service2_1 : IService2
{
    public int DoSomethingForService2()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

public interface IService2
{
    int DoSomethingForService2();
}
```

Now the Unity Container is built up.  We tend to use a separate project for this as we don't want all references to be held in the UI.  We are using 2 named registrations of IService2.

```
public static class UnityContainerBuilder
{
    public static IUnityContainer BuildDirectInUnity()
    {
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<IService2, Service2>("Service2OneAndOnly", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IService2, Service2_1>("Service2_1", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IService3, Service3>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IService1, Service1>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
            new InjectionConstructor(
                new ResolvedParameter<IService2>("Service2OneAndOnly"),
                new ResolvedParameter<IService3>()));
    }
}
```

Now the fun part.  Here we get the Unity Configuration:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Building Unity Container...");
    var container = (UnityContainer)UnityContainerBuilder.BuildDirectInUnity();

    Console.WriteLine("Listing Registrations...");

    FieldInfo policiesField = typeof(UnityContainer).GetFields(
                    BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                    BindingFlags.Instance).First(f => f.Name == "policies");

    FieldInfo parameterValuesField = typeof(SpecifiedConstructorSelectorPolicy).GetFields(
                    BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                    BindingFlags.Instance).First(f => f.Name == "parameterValues");

    FieldInfo paramNameField = typeof(ResolvedParameter).GetFields(
                    BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                    BindingFlags.Instance).First(f => f.Name == "name");

    var policies = (PolicyList)policiesField.GetValue(container);

    // build up a dictionary for loop below to use to get the lifetime manager
    var typeToRegistration = new Dictionary<Tuple<Type, string>, ContainerRegistration>();

    foreach (ContainerRegistration registration in container.Registrations)
    {
        typeToRegistration.Add(new Tuple<Type, string>(registration.RegisteredType, registration.Name), registration);
    }

    // now output the list
    foreach (ContainerRegistration registration in container.Registrations)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} to {1}, {2}, {3}", 
            registration.RegisteredType.Name, 
            registration.MappedToType.Name, 
            registration.Name ?? "[default]",
            registration.LifetimeManagerType.Name);

        // need to check for our InjectionConstructor - I need local = false
        IConstructorSelectorPolicy constructorPolicy = policies.Get<IConstructorSelectorPolicy>(
            new NamedTypeBuildKey(registration.MappedToType, registration.Name), false);

        // and I need SpecifiedConstructorSelectorPolicy as we are not using the default constructor
        if (constructorPolicy is SpecifiedConstructorSelectorPolicy)
        {
            var specifiedConstructorPolicy = constructorPolicy as SpecifiedConstructorSelectorPolicy;

            // now output the ResolvedParameters for type, name, lifetime manager
            var paramValues = (InjectionParameterValue[])parameterValuesField.GetValue(specifiedConstructorPolicy);

            foreach (var param in paramValues)
            {
                if (param is ResolvedParameter)
                {
                    var resolvedParam = param as ResolvedParameter;

                    var name = (string)paramNameField.GetValue(resolvedParam);
                    string lifeTimeManagerName = 
                        typeToRegistration[new Tuple<Type, string>(resolvedParam.ParameterType, name)].LifetimeManagerType.Name;

                    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}, {1}, {2}", param.ParameterTypeName, name ?? "[default]", lifeTimeManagerName);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", param.ParameterTypeName);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Complete");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The drawbacks of this is that it is purely reflection based hacking and that it does not support the InjectionFactory where you can configure a new instance of a type.